# SAS controller on Dell power edge 2950 server

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware, sas, tape

My knowledge on Dell server is growing daily, however there are many areas where I  still require assistance. For example,

Our institution recently purchased a LT2000 tape library system. This also came with a SAS controller card for porting to one of our power edge 2950 servers running ESXI 4.1. I have installed the card on the power edge, rebooted, however how do I verify that the card was installed correctly?

Also, do I have to do any other configurations to set up this card correctly.

Thanks for any insight

namich

Answer (score 1):

In VMWare vCenter or from the VMWare client, browse to the Server -> Configuration -> Storage Adapters and look for the adapter in the listing. In the example below, you'll see a SCSI card listed as "vmhba1". The numbering may be different in your case, but you'll see something similar.

You will also need to attach this SCSI/SAS card to the virtual machine running the backup software. [VMWare has a knowledge base article describing this process](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016407).

[image]